# How to translate OSM node ids to HERE node ids?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

I have part of an OSM way between two OSM node ids **5264306189** and **5264306190** (taken from [openstreetmap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/5264306189)) as you can see in the image below.

What would be the equivalent node ids, or what is the right way to translate/represent this in a HERE map and how?

This is the GeoJSON line string that i've used to visualize the line

```
{
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[
      101.1929014, 54.4496526],
      [101.1937758, 54.4494843]
    ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently HERE does not support a way to translate OSM node ids to HERE Link ID or vice versa.

Comment: I have GPS data on the road currently with OSM data which I would like to put on a HERE map. Given GPS data on the road what would be the best way to get the HERE node ids for each GPS coordinate + getting the road type? e.g lat1,lon1 is between node1 and node2, roadtype RESIDENTIAL

Comment: @AntonioGomezAlvarado, There is a rest api for route matching such as GPS data to retrieve some map attributes. Would you please have a look the documentation link? https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-matching/dev_guide/topics/matching-gps-traces.html